# Tracking progress with xargs

Tags: command-line-interface, xargs

I'm using xargs to execute a command on a set of input parameters something like this:

```
cat <someinput> | xargs -n 1 -P 5 <somecmd>
```

The input file is really long and  take a long time to run. So I'm just waiting for the command prompt to show up. Is there a way to display a progress bar for the number of input arguments that have completed?

I tried using 'bar' but I always got an 'infinite' throughput. It seems like xargs reads the entire input before executing commands.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wsgx.gif]

Answer (score 20):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
cat <someinput> | parallel --bar -P 5 <somecmd>
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: thank you very much (for the answer, and for writing the software!), it works great!

Answer (score 11):

You can use pv :

```
cat <someinput> | pv -p -s sizeof_someimput | xargs -n 1 -P 5 <somecmd>
```

With this you will know where the reading of *someimput* is, so you will know approximately where the treatment of *someimput* is.

Comment: Another frequent use-case might be the combination with find: `FIND=( find "$DIR" -type f ) && ${FIND[@]} -print0 | pv -0lps $(${FIND[@]} | wc -l) | xargs -0 -I {} -P 5 <somecmd>`

Comment: The issue I have when using this approach is that the pipe buffer consumes the entire input of the cat command, showing a "complete" progress bar, while the xargs command has just started

Comment: The solution to @MaxBileschi’s problem for me was to put `pv` after `xargs`: `xargs -n 1 -P 5 --verbose ‹somecmd› < ‹someinput› 2>&1 | pv -l -s $(wc -l < ‹someinput›) > /dev/null`

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for just a general indication of progress the simplest method is to just echo prior to doing the command you'd like to do.

Example:
`cat <someinput> | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {}; <somecmd>;'`

`-I{}` sets `{}` to the current string being processed

`sh -c` will allow you to execute multiple commands (note: semi-colon after every command is required *including the last one*.

Comment: you can use `xargs`'s `-t, --verbose` instead of `echo {};`